# Jquery Unobtrusive Validation fails after binding options to select dropdown dynamically in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: c#, razor-pages, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm developing a web app in asp.net core 3.0 razor pages. I have a partial view `_UserCreatePartial.cshtml` with a form id `#formUserCreate` for creating user. **All the inputs in the form are required**. I'm loading this partial view during parent page load using the `<partial>` tag helper.

```html
<!-- begin user create partial -->
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-purple f-s-12 mx-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userCreateModal">Add New User</button>
<div>
    <partial name="_UserCreatePartial" model="Model.UserCreateViewModel" />
</div>
<!-- end user create partial -->
```

Here is my `_UserCreatePartial`:

```html
<div class="modal fade p-0 d-print-none" role="dialog" aria-label="User Create" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
     id="userCreateModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-secondary">
                <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="h4 font-weight-600 modal-title">Create User</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="button" id="btnUserCreate" class="btn btn-sm btn-purple btn-rounded f-s-12 mr-2" value="Create">
                        <button type="button" id="btnUserCreateClose" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-purple btn-rounded f-s-12">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="formUserCreate" method="post">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label asp-for="BusinessId"></label>
                            <select asp-for="BusinessId" asp-items="Model.Businesses" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="BusinessId" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label asp-for="ClientId"></label>
                            <select asp-for="ClientId" asp-items="Model.Clients" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="ClientId" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initially this form is loaded with options in `#BusinessId` dropdown and with only `select` option in `#ClientId` dropdown

[image]

Now If i submit this form without selecting any values, validation is triggered for both inputs

[image]

Now when I change the options in the `#BusinessId` dropdown, a `fetch` call is made to server to get options that are needed to be binded to `#ClientId` dropdown.

Here is the code for that,

```js
document.addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
    if (e.target && e.target.id === 'BusinessId') {
        await handleLoadDropdown('#ClientId', e.target.value, window.userUrls.getClients);
    }
});

handleLoadDropdown = async (target, value, url) => {
    const select = document.querySelector(target);
    if (value) {
        await fetchGetAsync(url, { id: value }, window.gallaConstant.jsonDataType).then((response) => {
            select.options.length = 0;
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = 'Select';
            select.appendChild(option);
            response.Response.forEach(response => {
                option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = response.Text;
                option.value = response.Value;
                select.appendChild(option);
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        select.options.length = 0;
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = 'Select';
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#formUserCreate");
},
```

Now if I submit the form, jquery unobtrusive validation fails for `#ClientId` dropdown.

[image]

I changed the selected option of the `#BusinessId` dropdown back to default option `select`. Now If I click on submit only `#BusinessId` is getting validated.

[image]

I tried re initializing the validation using `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#formUserCreate")` or even for the control `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#ClientId");` after `fetch` call is made to the server. But still it is not working. Any clues on where I'm going wrong? Am I missing anything? Please assist.

Comment: So I need to have initial form loaded with no `options` in `#ClientId`? and on change of `#BusinessId` I need to bind all the data including `Select` `option` from the server response?. I'm still not clear with your comments. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Since you're not using an mvvm framework, forget what I said above. Do this: After you do this `option.text = 'Select';` also do this `option.value = null`. Or include an option for that in your data from the backend. Try that and see.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I tried both the ways. Setting the `select` option from the backed or adding `option.value = null` in js. Both didn't work. please assist

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue at the moment. I've brought a partial view back via AJAX/jquery and injected it inside an existing form on the page. My partial view has a dropdownlist (Html.DropDownList) in it. I have used data-val="true" and data-val-required but they are not being respected.. I want them to enforce the dropdownlist as being mandatory...